# Loading python modules through a computing cluster

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have an account to a computing cluster that uses Scientific Linux. Of course I only have user access. I'm working with python and I need to run python scripts, so I need to import some python modules. Since I don't have root access, I installed a local python copy on my $HOME with all the required modules. When I run the scripts on my account (hosting node), they run correctly. But in order to submit jobs to the computing queues (to process on much faster machines), I need to submit a bash script that has a line that executes the scripts. The computing cluster uses SunGrid Engine. However when I submit the bash script, I get an error that the modules I installed can't be found!

So my understanding to the problem is that the modules are not sent or something to the machine that executes the script. My question is: is it possible to include all the modules in the script or so?

**EDIT**: I just created a bash script that runs `which python` and I noticed that the output was NOT my python copy. But when I run 'which python' on my ssh account, I get my python copy correctly..

Answer (score 0):

The submitted script is most likely using the system Python installation and not your own. Try submitting a shell script with only one command, `which python`, to confirm.

The fix is to prepend the path to your Python interpreter to your system path. On my machine, the right Python is installed at `/Users/mbatchkarov/anaconda/bin/python`. I added `export PATH="/Users/mbatchkarov/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` to `~/.bash_profile`

EDIT Add the same line to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Please see my edit. On my ssh account everything is setup correctly, but when I send the job to run, it uses some other python.

Comment: See my edit. If it works when you ssh into the compute nodes, then SGE must be spawning non-login shells. You can read about the difference between login and non-login shell here http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile